# How to split a string in c# with a variable?

Tags: c#

I can't split a string with a variable:

```
string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Global.filepath);
string relativePath = ofd.FileName.Split(directoryName);
```

I get this error for directoryName: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'"

Has anyone an other idea?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, you can't store the results of a `string.Split` in a single string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) of Split string `Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)`

```
var relativePath = ofd.FileName.Split(new string[] { directoryName}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific overload you can use for this.

Try something like

```
ofd.FileName.Split(directoryName, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or

```
ofd.FileName.Split(new string[] { directoryName }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_

The above will help

```
string[] relativePath = ofd.FileName.Split(directoryName, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good start is as usual to read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split). There you see many overloads of `string.split` method.

In your case you try to use

```
public string[] Split (string separator, StringSplitOptions options = System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

but it return `string[]` not `string`

```
string[] path = ofd.FileName.Split(directoryName)
```